# Chrome + jQuery hide/show inline

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, show

I have these things

```
<ul class="ul_std"  style="float:right">
             <li class="action_buttons" ><a id="button_deleteNormal" class="button_small button_small_red"  >Διαγραφή</a></li>
                <li class="action_buttons"><a id="button_editCancel" class="button_small"  >Ακύρωση Τροποποίησης</a></li>
                <li class="action_buttons"><a id="button_editNormal" class="button_small"  >Τροποποίηση</a></li>
                <li class="action_buttons" style="margin-right:0" ><a id="button_addNormal" class="button_small">Προσθήκη</a></li>
              </ul>
```

The problem is that i hide all of them except the anchor with id = button_addNormal
at $(document).ready()...
Everything works fine but at chrome when i want to show them ,it displays them as display:inline and not as display:inline-block ...
The css class button_small have display:inline-block....

Firefox,IE 6+ works ok... Havent tested on safari but i hope that it would be ok...

Why chrome kills inline-block?
The solution was to put .css("display","inline-block") instead of .show()

Comment: Do you set "display:inline-block" manually? Do you mind pasting your jQuery code?

Comment: where?My jquery code is 300 lines...
Actually i do a hide on document ready
$("#button_deleteNormal").hide();
    $("#button_editCancel").hide();
    $("#button_editNormal").hide();

then when i try to do

$("#button_deleteNormal").show();
    $("#button_editCancel").show();
    $("#button_editNormal").show();

it gets inline not inline-block.....
Only in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a web store system in jsp, and a catch this error in last week. I think this problem is a caching problem, because a code works in Users.jsp, and same code not in Subjects.jsp. Both code work in FF, IE, Opera. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.
Use hide('slow'), it's same solution...

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this in chrome (at least in latest and **5.0.356.2** beta) based on your question.
[See a working demo here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vvuj/).

When I hide all but the last one with `$('ul li a:not(#button_addNormal)').hide();` and show them all again, it comes back as `inline-block`.  I tested in jQuery **1.3.2**, **1.4.2**, and **nightly**, same result (also tested/working in latest stable chrome: **4.1.129.1042**).

Something else is breaking this in your page, hard to say what without the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use $("#something").css("display", "block"); instead of show. (or inline-block)